# Rails 'returning' method - One-liner to build Array from Multiple Arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

How do I convert the following to a clear one-liner in ruby?

```
def questions
  results = []
  sections.each do |section|
    results = results.concat(Question.find_all_by_survey_section_id(section.id))
  end
  results
end
```

I feel like I could use the `&:` (`Symbol#to_proc`) and `returning` methods in there somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that SurveySection `has_many :questions`, you can simplify this to:

```
sections.map(&:questions).flatten
```

Or if the method is defined in an ActiveRecord model, you could just declare that it `has_many :questions, :through => :sections` and you won't have to define the method at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
def questions
  sections.map do |section|
    Question.find_all_by_survey_section_id(section.id)
  end.flatten
end
```

or

```
def questions
  sections.inject([]) do |all, section|
    all.concat Question.find_all_by_survey_section_id(section.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map or collect, like so

```
def questions
  sections.map{|section| Question.find_all_by_survey_section_id(section.id)}.flatten
end
```

However, I dont think you can use symbol to proc for this because you are not just calling a method on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Without a block in sight:

```
def questions
  sections.map(&:id).flat_map(&Question.method(:find_all_by_survey_section_id))
end
```